# Open MPI error with doMPI

Tags: r, openmpi, dompi

I am having an issue running `doMPI` on our Linux clusters. I am trying to run the `sincMPI.R` example problem in the `doMPI` package with an `mpirun -n 1 Rscript sincMPI.R` command. The error I am getting is:

> Open MPI does not support recursive calls of mpiexec

I should mention that I am able to load the `doMPI` and `Rmpi` libraries, so I believe that means they were installed correctly. Perhaps this is just an OpenMPI issue?

Comment: What if you `Rscript sincMPI.R` ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had tried this previously. When I `Rscript sincMPI.R`, I get the following error: "mpiexec: Error: unknown option "-pmi_args""